# R: Sum variable values conditional on value of other variable

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation, recode

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
  year country inhabitants
1    1       A          15
2    2       A          10
3    3       A          24
4    1       B          76
5    2       B          69
6    3       B          58
7    1       C         120
8    2       C         131
9    3       C         128
```

Now, I would like to create the sum of "inhabitants" for each year, over all countries.
I.e., my solution would look like:

```
  year country inhabitants sum_inhabitants
1    1       A          15             211
2    2       A          10             210
3    3       A          21             207
4    1       B          76             211
5    2       B          69             210
6    3       B          58             207
7    1       C         120             211
8    2       C         131             210
9    3       C         128             207
```

My original data frame contains many more observations, which is why I can't do the computation by hand.

Comment: It would be great if you could supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. That way others can also befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.  Also,  please outline what you have already already tried.

Comment: @EricFail look for a different dupe without cumulative sums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ave` to sum by year with no need for outside packages. The advantage that it has over `aggregate` is that it will not summarize but rather fill in-line:

```
df$sum_inhabitants <- ave(df$inhabitants, df$year, FUN=sum)
# year country inhabitants sum_inhabitants
# 1    1       A          15             211
# 2    2       A          10             210
# 3    3       A          21             207
# 4    1       B          76             211
# 5    2       B          69             210
# 6    3       B          58             207
# 7    1       C         120             211
# 8    2       C         131             210
# 9    3       C         128             207
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Is there a way to ignore NAs in "inhabitants"?

Comment: Yes. `ave(df$inhabitants, df$year, FUN=function(x) sum(x, na.rm=T))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` package, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(sum_inhabitants = sum(inhabitants))
```

If you really want to retain duplicates in that column and add it to original data frame, change `summarise` above to `mutate`, and that will give you the exact output you specified above.

If you want to get it by year and by country, you can do this:

```
df %>% group_by(year, country) %>% summarise(sum_inhabitants = sum(inhabitants))
```